# JSR 303 Bean validation

Tags: java, javabeans, bean-validation

I have two fields in my bean

```
String key,
String value,
```

When field key="A" , "value" should follow a particular Regex 
for other "key" - it can be anything.

How would I define this validation on value based on key.

Comment: Implement it as object level validation.

Comment: Object level validation cannot be performed as it is not a standard approach when doing REST Services - the validation is left to the Container ( Hibernate library for bean validation)

Comment: I don't understand that comment :(.

Comment: hmm .. when u say object level validation - u mean - if(Object.getA()=="A"){ apply regex pattern } ..

Comment: I meant _object level constraints_ (http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-requirements-object).

Answer (score 2):

You can use class-level constraints.

1- Annotate your bean with class-level custom constraint annotation:

```
@ValidKeyValue
public class MyBean {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    ...
}
```

2- [Create the custom annotation and its validator.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-implementing-classlevel-constraint)

3- Implement your validation logic in the `isValid` method:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(MyBean myBean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if ("A".equals(myBean.getKey())) {
        // case 1
    } else {
        // case 2
    }
}
```